# Как совместить asyncio и aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

пишу телеграм бота на языке Python и библиотеке aiogram, у меня возникла необходимость при перезапуске файла выполнять функцию, покопавшись немного в интернете нашёл вот такое решение

```
bot = Bot(config.bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def hello():
    await bot.send_message(my_id, 'Bot started!')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.run_until_complete(hi())
    loop.close()
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=hi())
```

Функция `hello` выполняется успешно, мне в чат с ботом приходит сообщение, но сразу же после этого бот падает из-за вот такой ошибки:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._startup_polling' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._shutdown_polling' was never awaited
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём тут проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так погодите ка. Вам же просто нужно чтобы при запуске бота запускалась определенная функция? Вам не нужен asynio для этого. Сделайте вот так

```py
bot = Bot(config.bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    await bot.send_message(my_id, 'Bot started!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```